# where is PROJECT_DIRECTORY in YCM-Generator

Tags: linux, vim, editor, youcompleteme

I Installed YouCompleteMe on vim.

For python it works, but not for C/C++.

I tried to install YCM-Generator, but I don't understand where `PROJECT_DIRECTORY` is in my Linux environment.

```
Run ./config_gen.py PROJECT_DIRECTORY, where PROJECT_DIRECTORY is the root directory of your project's build system (i.e. the one containing the root Makefile, etc.)
```

Answer (score 1):

`PROJECT_DIRECTORY` is where your application lives, it's where you put all your files. So it can be anywhere on your system.

Comment: what application ?
what files ?
YouCompleteMe directory?

Comment: i get this message : ERROR: Unknown build system

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14032/vim-youcompleteme).

I'm not sure if this solves the problem for you, but for me making a simple file named `.ycm_extra_conf.py` in the folder containing my files, i.e those I edit using vim, solved the problem.
I just put the below code in the file:

```
def FlagsForFile( filename, **kwargs ): 
    return {
      'flags': [ '-x', 'c', '-Wall', '-Wextra', '-Werror' ], 
    }
```